# Mocking with h5py returning dictionary in Python

Tags: python, pytest, h5py, pytest-mock

I have the following in a function:

```
import h5py

with h5py.File(path, 'r') as f:
    big = f['big']
    box = f['box']
```

I'm currently writing a test for the function where I try to mock it
by something like:

```
def test_function(mocker):
    mocker.patch("h5py.File", new=mocker.mock_open())
    ...
```

Where mocker comes from: https://pypi.org/project/pytest-mock/

What I want to achieve is for the *mock* to return me a *dict* by the name of *f* so I'm able to interact with it such as in the function above.

Is this possible, I'm prepared to use whatever brute force solution possible out there...

br.
KJ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54634817/mocking-a-class-used-in-a-with-statement), you need to ensure the result of `h5py.File().__enter__()` returns an appropriate dictionary:

```
from unittest import mock
import h5py
import pytest


def foo():
    with h5py.File('.', 'r') as f:
        big = f['big']
        box = f['box']

    return big, box


def test_foo(mocker):
    d = {'big': 1, 'box': 2}

    m = mocker.MagicMock()
    m.__enter__.return_value = d

    mocker.patch("h5py.File",
                 return_value=m)

    assert foo() == (1,2)
```